# Is the ononline event supported in a service worker?

Tags: service-worker, service-worker-events

`document.ononline` is an event available in the browser. Is there an equivalent event supported by service worker code, which does not have DOM access?

All the sample code I have seen checks network status in the course of handling a request. It would be desirable to respond to network availability immediately for the purposes of committing local updates to the server or cloud.

The best I could find in terms of documentation was https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope and it lists only these events:

- onactivate
- onfetch
- oninstall
- onmessage
- onnotificationclick
- onnotificationclose
- onpush
- onpushsubscriptionchange
- onsync

Of these, sync seems most like what I seek, but it depends on use of a SyncManager, and the documentation for that is fraught with warnings against use in production code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether there's an event available in the SW for that. Someone should confirm this.

You could work around this problem by having the ononline event handler logic in your page's JS which could inform the SW of the connectivity changes. This would also be an appropriate place to handle any notifications in the UI for the user.

Spesifically:

- SW registers an onmessage handler
- Client/page JS registers a handler for the ononline event
- When connection changes, the handler notifies the SW via postMessage API
- SW receives the connection change msg from the client and acts accordingly

The postMessage API is very useful and can be used to pass basically any data between the page and the SW. Note that there isn't any spesific message for my proposal, just pass something like { "new_status": "online" } etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but one I'm currently interested in. What I've found is that while MDN currently [says it's supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/ononline) in the (shared) WorkerGlobalScope, I'm sitting on a breakpoint right now in my service worker using Chrome DevTools and the ServiceWorkerGlobalScope does not have an "ononline" property. The "navigator.onLine" indicator appears to work however. You can at least check that and return cached responses immediately.

I added event listeners for online and offline events and neither triggered, so it appears to be unsupported. I can think of plausible reasons for not supporting it, but it would be interesting to hear the real ones.

Comment: Crikey, it's been so long I didn't even remember writing the question till I read it. But that's a promising line of investigation.  Thanks for suggesting navigator.online. The trouble with polling that is either you poll it frequently which is antisocial in a mobile device, or you miss narrow windows. But it's a whole lot better than nothing. What I think is needed is a way to queue some code for execution when the network becomes available; wake on LAN you might say.